# Not returning a login

Tags: php, mysqli

The registration part works. The sign up buttons and login buttons bring it to the page I want, however, it is not logging them to where the page they gt to is theirs alone, instead, it's bringing them to a general page, so they are not able to save their profile data. It's not even showing the erros upon signup on the index.php page.

connection.php

```
<?php

    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");

    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {

        echo "Could not connect to database";
    }

?>
```

login.php

```
<?php

    session_start();

    include("connection.php");

    if ($_POST['submit']=="Sign Up") {

        if (!$_POST['email']) $error.="<br />Please enter your email";
            else if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) $error.="<br />Please enter a valid email address";

        if (!$_POST['password']) $error.="<br />Please enter your password";
            else {

            if (strlen($_POST['password'])<8) $error.="<br />Please enter a password with at least 8 characters";
            if (!preg_match('`[A-Z]`', $_POST['password'])) $error.="<br />Please enter at least 1 capital letter";

            }

         if ($error) $error = "There were error(s) in your signup details:".$error;
         else {


            $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE email='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."'";

            $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

            $results = mysqli_num_rows($result);

            if ($results) $error = "That email address is already registered";

            else {

                $query="INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."', '".md5(md5($_POST['email']).$_POST['password'])."')";

                mysqli_query($link, $query);

                $error = "You've been signed up!";

                $_SESSION['id']=mysqli_insert_id($link);


                header("Location:profile.php");

            }

        }

    }

     if ($_POST['submit']=="Log In") {

        $query="SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE email='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['loginemail'])."' AND password='".md5(md5($_POST['loginemail']).$_POST['loginpassword'])."' LIMIT 1";

        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        if ($row) {

            $_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];

                header("Location:dashboard.php");

            } else {

             $error = "We could not find a user with that email and password. Please try again.";
            }

        }

?>
```

index.php

```
    <section data-scroll-reveal="enter bottom, move 20px, over 2s, wait 0.3s" class="mainslider">
    <div class="contentContainer" id="firstContainer">  
        <div class="container-fluid">       
            <div class="row" class="center">        
                    <br /><br />            
                <h3 class="companyMotto navChange">A Debt Accelerator Company</h3>              
                    <div style="background:transparent !important" class="jumbotron jumbotronHome">                     
                        <h1 class="quotes"><strong>We&#8217;re serious about <br /> getting you results</strong></h1>   
                        <h3><font color="#d24837">Get Started! It's FREE!</font></h3>                               
                    </div>  

                    <?php                        
                        if ($error) {                            
                            echo '<div class="alert alert danger">'.addslashes($error).'</div>';                         
                        }  

                        if ($message) {                            
                            echo '<div class="alert alert success">'.addslashes($message).'</div>';                         
                        }                                       
                    ?>      

                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">                                                      
                            <form method="post" action="login.php">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Email Address"  value="<?php echo addslashes ($_POST['email']); ?>" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Create a Password"  value="<?php echo addslashes ($_POST['password']); ?>" />
                                </div>                                                                  
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-kani btn-lg" value="Sign Up"/>
                                </div>                                      
                            </form>                     
                    </div>              
              </div>                 
         </div>                         
    </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: `md5(md5(` this really doesn't do much. Not even if you would do `md5(md5(md5(`

Comment: The name of your inputs and your attempt to retrieve the values from post don't even match up.

Comment: Really??? I thought md5(md5 was about the best you could do for passwords!! Do you have any other suggestions? As far as matching up, I'm not quite catching it.

Answer (score 0):

In file login.php on line 7, you should only use `if ($_POST['submit']) {`

Comment: I would but I have two submit values, one for "Log In" and the other for "Submit". The header location is different for both.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, fixed it by changing:

```
if ($_POST['submit']=="Sign Up")
```

which is linked to:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Sign Up" />
```

and

```
if ($_POST['submit']=="Log In")
```

which links to:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Log in" />
```

Changed to this:

```
if ($_POST['signup'])
    <input type="submit" name="signup" value="Sign Up" />
```

and

```
if ($_POST['login'])
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log in" />
```

And now it works, I am wondering if it has to do with the PHP version on my server, which is 5.5.
Hope this helps anyone else in the same bind.